# Problems with installing facepy

Tags: python, facepy

when i run the code `pip install facepy`, it comes with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/djibrilkeita/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
```

and it goes on too

```
"/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 565, in resolve
raise DistributionNotFound(req)  # XXX put more info here
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pip==1.4.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a similar problem with Pip: [pip broke. how to fix DistributionNotFound error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200056/pip-broke-how-to-fix-distributionnotfound-error).

The error seems to happen when you use different management tools to download packages, ie. easy_install vs. brew vs. pybrew, etc.