# "pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound" at pip and easy install

Tags: python-2.7, pip, easy-install

I have to install a package via pip (in detail: the package lxml) into Python2.7 on our server (running on ScientificLinux).
There is running Python 2.6 and 2.7.

The command `pip` points to our Python2.6 installation where the package already exists. When I try to run pip-2.7, he is throwing the following errors:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip-2.7", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2659, in <module>
    parse_requirements(__requires__), Environment()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 546, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pip==1.4.1
```

Thats a well known problem here ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200056/pip-broke-how-to-fix-distributionnotfound-error)), but the accepted answer doesn't work. When I want to upgrade pip via easy_install, I get a similar error like the one above:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/easy_install", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2659, in <module>
    parse_requirements(__requires__), Environment()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 546, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: distribute==0.6.49
```

I found already a possible solution [here](http://www.branchpond.net/blog/fixing-broken-pip-and-distribute), but it also doesn't help, the versions are set right :/

Comment: `pip-2.7` is referring to the Python 2.6 `site-packages` directory. That shouldn't be happening.

Comment: That's right, that have I noticed, too. (But forget to mention -.-). And how can I fix that?

Comment: Can you post the output of `python -m site` ?

Comment: Of course. Output is too long for comments, see it [here](http://pastebin.com/DTvf1CYd) on pastebin.
I made it with python and python2.7...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using one of the installers on [Christopher Gohlke's site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)? This is a tremendous resource for Windows users (I myself have found them extremely helpful.) He has a number of lxml installers.