# Python pip says: pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pip==1.4.1

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, pip

I just did a clean install of Ubuntu 14.04 and also installed pycharm. Pycharm said setuptools and pip weren't installed and offered to install it. I simply clicked "Ÿes" and it seemed to install it. A bit after that I wanted to install Flask (which is awesome btw) using pip, so I did `sudo pip install flask`. To my surprise it said the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2797, in <module>

  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 576, in resolve
    def resolve(self, requirements, env=None, installer=None,
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pip==1.4.1
```

So I simply tried the regular way: I downloaded get-pip.py and ran that, but that says: `Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`

I found some other [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20282679/pkg-resources-distributionnotfound-at-pip-and-easy-install) [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19400370/easy-install-and-pip-broke-pkg-resources-distributionnotfound-distribute-0-6) here on SO, which suggested to look in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`, but that folder is empty.

Does anybody know what's wrong and how I can fix this? All tips are welcome!

Comment: I use ubuntu 14.04 with no  issues but I upgraded. If you `sudo easy_install pip==1.5.1` does it make any difference?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - Awesome! That solved it!

Comment: Thanks it worked great `sudo easy_install pip==1.5.4`

Answer (score 18):

Had the same problem under 12.04.

Did `sudo easy_install pip==1.4.1` and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Faced the same problem with ubuntu 14.04 ,python2.7 and pip 1.5.4

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python2.7
sudo apt-get purge python-pip
wget https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py
sudo python get-pip.py
sudo pip install package-name
```

This worked!

Comment: Thanks, this also worked for me on an ubuntu 14.04. easy_install was broken the same way as pip, so the above solutions were not applicable.