# Python pip 1.5 issues with setuptools

Tags: python, pip, easy-install

My system uses x64 bit processor and Windows 8.1.

I installed:

1. Python 2.7.6 (32 bit)
2. then easy_install (2.7)
3. then python27>easy_install pip
4. test pip: python27>pip install bottle. I get message: "Wheel installs require setuptools >= 0.8 for dist-info support."

Please advise solutions.

Thanks.

Comment: you probably need to install/upgrade setuptools

Comment: Install [setuptools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools).

Comment: I think that this question / answer may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20905350/latest-pip-fails-with-requires-setuptools-0-8-for-dist-info/20906394#20906394

Answer (score -1):

Install setuptools from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools. That should do the trick.