# Why does 'pip' require "setuptools >= 0.8" even though I have 2.1 installed?

Tags: python, version, pip, setuptools

When I attempt [certain commands](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20905350/656912) with `pip`, I get an error message stating that `pip`

```
“requires setuptools >= 0.8 for dist-info”
```

even though I have, according to `yolk -l` (as well as `pip list`), a much higher version of `setuptools` installed:

```
pip             - 1.5          - active 
...
setuptools      - 2.1          - active
```

Why is `pip` asking for a version of `setuptools` >= 0.8? Isn't 2.1 > 0.8; or is my installation not in fact at the version that `yolk` is reporting? Is there something I need to do to ensure that I in fact do have "setuptools >= 0.8"?

Comment: Note that this is different from the question about what to do about the error message (answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20906394/656912)). This is a question about what is causing the error and whether there is in fact a version ">= 0.8" that I should have installed.

Comment: This appears to have been fixed in 1.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

You may have more than one setuptools installed. If there is a link to lower version pip would see that one.
For example python usually appears on both usr/bin and usr/local/bin, I had a similar version problem and renamed the one in usr/local/bin. if this is the case you should find out which versions are installed and rename/remove the lower version.