# Django and pip installation

Tags: django

In mac terminal, I typed `sudo easy_install pip` and I'm being asked for a password.  Where do I find this password?  My terminal currently reads:

> Last login: Mon Jan 13 10:44:09 on ttys000
>
> stephens-mbp:~ stephenmadigan$ sudo easy_install pip
>
> WARNING: Improper use of the sudo command could lead to data loss or
>   the deletion of important system files. Please double-check your
>   typing when using sudo. Type "man sudo" for more information.
>
> To proceed, enter your password, or type Ctrl-C to abort.
>
> Password:

Answer (score 1):

You're using `sudo`, which "elevates" the terminal to a privileged account, typically root. To do this, you need to supply the password for the administrator account.

You would have normally set a password for your account when installing OS X. It's the same password you usually need to enter when installing software, or when you try to do anything in OS X that requires permissions - for example:

[image]

You haven't said which version of OS X you're using, but there's more information on sudo passwords [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4103).

Comment: 10.9.1 version - I thought I tried the correct password that I install Mac software but it didn't work.  Thanks I'll try again.

Comment: Got it...must have been missing something in my password...darn powerbook sticky keys.

Comment: further typed pip install django and got the following message:Wheel installs require setuptools >= 0.8 for dist-info support.
pip's wheel support requires setuptools >= 0.8 for dist-info support.
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/stephenmadigan/Library/Logs/pip.log

Comment: Possibly covered here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20905350/latest-pip-fails-with-requires-setuptools-0-8-for-dist-info - try `sudo pip install setuptools --no-use-wheel --upgrade` maybe?

Comment: I was going to try that if it was the only solution...not sure how --no-use-wheel --upgrade effects the install.

Comment: Great, glad it worked. Remember to mark this question answered ;)