# How can I upgrade setup tools in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, pip, setuptools

I was trying to install some flask extensions in my virtual environment, but got this error:

```
flask/bin/pip install flask-wtf==0.8.4

Wheel installs require setuptools >= 0.8 for dist-info support.
pip's wheel support requires setuptools >= 0.8 for dist-info support.
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/seanpatterson/.pip/pip.log
```

In order to upgrade setup tools - the reason I assumed - I ran the following with no joy, the output was:

```
pip install -U setuptools

-bash: pip: command not found
```

So I then tried the following on recommendation:

```
flask/bin/pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

I still get an error:

```
sim1-3010:microblog seanpatterson$ flask/bin/pip install --upgrade setuptools Wheel     
installs require setuptools >= 0.8 for dist-info support. pip's wheel support requires   
setuptools >= 0.8 for dist-info support. Storing debug log for failure in 
/Users/seanpatterson/.pip/pip.log.
```

I'm very new to programming, and now it feels like I'm going around in circles as it seems to be saying I can't install setup tools because I need a newer version of setuptool to do so?!?!?

Comment: How did you create the virtualenv in the first place?

Comment: I'm surprised you get the error message, however, as Flask-WTF 0.8.4 doesn't have a wheel distribution.

Comment: I download this file https://raw.github.com/pypa/virtualenv/1.9.X/virtualenv.py, create the virtual environment in the app folder 'python virtualenv.py flask'

Comment: possible duplicate of [Latest 'pip' fails with "requires setuptools >= 0.8 for dist-info"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20905350/latest-pip-fails-with-requires-setuptools-0-8-for-dist-info)

Answer (score 0):

These recent problems with virtualenv are in the the recent 0.11 release. Most of the bugs with that release are already fixed and will soon appear in a 0.11.1 release. In the meantime you can downgrade your virtualenv to 0.10.1 or install the latest one with all the fixes from github.

Some of the reported issues:

- https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/521
- https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/524
- https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/518
- https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/532

Comment: If you have pip installed you can just use `pip uninstall`. If you don't have pip, then I would just go to the `bin` and `site-packages` directories and remove any references to virtualenv. After that install 0.10.1.

Answer (score 0):

Realised what I had done.

It appears (my best guess!) that I hadn't upgraded setup tools at the system level, so I did this:

```
sudo easy_install -U setuptools
```

I then recreated the virtual environment, presumably now has access to the upgraded setuptools, and I've been able to install the modules.