# pip's wheel support requires setuptools >= 0.8 for dist-info support

Tags: pip

I have a Jenkins server running Ubuntu which has been running perfectly fine for as long as I've been using it, and in one of the jobs, it runs a few things under the shiningpanda plugin (a python virtual environment wrapper).

At some point today, or over the weekend, the job that uses it started failing, with the main error seemingly being the title, full error reported is

```
> pip install Jinja2
Wheel installs require setuptools >= 0.8 for dist-info support.
pip's wheel support requires setuptools >= 0.8 for dist-info support.
```

I've googled for this error, or anything like it, but I haven't been able to find anything useful towards solving it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This seems to be a `pip` issue that is [not Ubuntu-specific](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20905350/656912). For some

```
sudo pip install setuptools --no-use-wheel --upgrade ...
```

appears to have worked.

The `--no-use-wheel` option simply skips use of ['wheel archives'](http://wheel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#wheel), but otherwise preforms exactly the same install as a command that omits it.