# Error installing package with pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I'm trying to install a charting tool ([matplotlib-v1.4.2](http://matplotlib.org/downloads.html)) for python 3.4 in Windows 7, so far all my trails doesn't seem to do the job.

**Attempts:**

- I've downloaded pip from [GitHub](https://github.com/pypa/pip)
- `python -m pip install matplotlib` on Command Prompt[DOS] - No Use

There's a similar question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21222151/1463551), tried these suggestions too but I get the following error

**`'$' is not reconginized as an internal or external command.`**

I'm sure I'm missing something, your step by step guidance on this regard would be much appreciated.

Comment: There is almost nothing in this question or answer about whl files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `$` refers to the beginning of a shell prompt, you shouldn't actually include it in your command :)

So rather than (from the example question you posted)

```
$ pip install requests
```

you actually *type*

```
pip install requests
```

In any case, you can download matplotlib .exe files from [here](http://matplotlib.org/downloads.html) for use in Windows. Make sure you get the correct bitness (32bit vs 64bit) and the correct Python version.

Answer (score 1):

`$` in the example signifies the linux prompt, which in windows is usually `>`

You can install the library by either using `pip install`, or using this link http://matplotlib.org/downloads.html
Additionally, most python packages for windows can be easily installed by using the installers from this site http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/