# Installing Anaconda Python, pyhdf, and netcdf4 for windows 64 bit

Tags: python, numpy, module, netcdf, pyhdf

I am pretty new to python and programming , all self taught.  I started a new position late last year requiring me to create and maintain large scientific data sets.  A big hurdle was learning to install the pyhdf and netcdf4 modules for 64 bit python 2.7 on windows.  Here is how to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**NEW CONDENSED VERSION ----- JUNE 2016**

I have learned more since I wrote this question.  Anaconda makes everything except pyhdf (to my knowledge) easier.

**1. Anaconda**

Download Anaconda 2.7 windows 64 bit from [here!](http://continuum.io/downloads) and install at  C:\Anaconda

**2. Numpy**

```
conda update numpy
```

**3. PIP**

```
conda update pip
```

**4. Pyhdf**

Download pyhdf python 2.7 64 bit from [here!](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

```
pip install C:\Users\username\Downloads\pyhdf_file
```

**5. Netcdf**

```
conda update netcdf4
```

=========================================================================

=========================================================================

**OLD METHOD  ----- OCTOBER 2014**

**1. Anaconda**

Download Anaconda 2.7 windows 64 bit from [here!](http://continuum.io/downloads) and install at  C:\Anaconda

**2. Numpy**

In command prompt.  You could also use the below method to pip install numpy.

```
conda install numpy
```

**3. PIP**

I used the directions found [here!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21222114/how-do-i-install-python-libraries). They are also found below.

Download [ez_setup.py](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py) and then run:

```
python ez_setup.py
```

Then download [get-pip.py](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py) and run:

```
python get-pip.py
```

upgrade installed setuptools by pip:

```
pip install setuptools --upgrade
```

**4. Pyhdf**

Download pyhdf python 2.7 64 bit from [here!](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

```
pip install C:\Users\username\Downloads\pyhdf_file
```

**5. Netcdf**

Download netcdf4 python 2.7 64 bit from [here!](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

```
pip install C:\Users\username\Downloads\netcdf4_file
```

Comment: +1 I was in a similar situation this week and this is a good way to go. In fact I was just going to post a comment about the  easier way to install that you have just added! I was following your old method when I thought to check whether `conda` supports netCDF, and it does...