# cannot locate pip.pm for installing python modules

Tags: python, regex, installation, pip

I'm having trouble installing the [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module for python, and would appreciate any suggestion and help. When I used "pip install" on a Windows system, the following error shows up:

Can't locate pip.pm in @INC <@INC contains: C:/Perl64/site/lib C:/Perl64/lib .) at C:\pathA\pathB\perl\bin/pip line 5. 
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\pathA\pathB\perl\bin/pip line 5.

All I did previously is to install pip, following this post: [How do I install Python libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21222114/how-do-i-install-python-libraries)

I succeeded in the following steps:

```
python ez_setup.py
python get-pip.py
```

but not:

```
pip install setuptools --upgrade
```

that is when I got the errors.

I am not familiar with using python on Windows, but I need to do it this time. Seems like there is another pip installed for perl on this computer, but when I check the environment variables, I can't really see anything about pip.

For your information -- the python version is:
2.7.7 |Anaconda 2.0.1 (64-bit)| (default, Jun 11 2014, 10:40:02) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Comment: Try following the instructions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4750806/1426065) instead.

Comment: you seem to use `anaconda`. You can use `conda install pip` and `conda install setuptools` instead. Also `python -m pip install setuptools --upgrade`  will probably work for you.

Comment: Thank you MattDMo, I should just ask where to locate pip -- soon after I changed the environment variable as indicated in that post, pip works. And thank you @cel, I was able to find correct pip under the Anaconda folder! Problem solve:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently Perl also has a tool named `pip`. Your `PATH` variable contains the directory for Perl's `pip` before the one containing Python's `pip`. You need to find the location of Python's `pip` and run it directly using an absolute path or edit the `PATH` variable for Windows so that the directory containing Python's `pip` is before the directory containing Perl's `pip`.

Comment: Hi there thank you for the answer - the question was really old and I almost forgot about it lol. Nonetheless I got a new computer and no longer use perl so this never happened again:)

Comment: @Helene I just ran into the same problem today and found a solution. I figured I might as well share. I do not think many people have both Perl and Python installed on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

The answers is perfect. Just a addon: you can do that by

1. Right click on the start button
2. Go to system> Advanced system settings> Environment Variables
3. In system variables select path and then click on edit
4. Reorder paths so that **C:\Python27** entry comes before the ***perl\bin***
   entry
5. Save your changes by clicking ok