# Installing Pygame Module

Tags: python, pygame

I have been trying to install the pygame module and get the error

> ImportError: No module named 'pygame'.

I currently have Python version 3.3.4 and installed pygame cp33 32-Bit.

It is currently a whl file and I have tried following tutorials etc in order to import it but I'm having no luck.

Comment: Are you running Python 32 bit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Python libraries?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21222114/how-do-i-install-python-libraries)

Comment: How did you install pygame?  How are you importing it?

Comment: i have downloaded pygame cp33 as whl file. i have pygame 3.3.4 downloaded and running in 64 bit.

Comment: 32 Bit*****
pygame is saved in my downloads folder and python on the C: drive

Answer (score 0):

Is your Python installation 64 Bit? If your python is a 64 bit version the binary install for the 32 bit will not work.

From [pygame](http://www.pygame.org/hifi.html) website:
*windows 64bit users note: use the 32bit python with this 32bit pygame.*
So either download a 32bit python, then install with the 32bit pygame installer, or download the unofficial 64bit pygame build at [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame).

Comment: I'm running the 32 bit python but still not getting anywhere, is there any more details i could provide you which would help>

Answer (score 0):

Information in this question is vague. But one common mistake is running Python in 64bit mode, something that isn't officially supported by Pygame as of yet.

There are binaries that can be downloaded here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame

**Note:** This answer is a standard answer for those searching the web and ending up here later on, might not solve OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

You can easy install and check which version fits you by downloading PyCharm IDE. When you download it, go to:

1. File
2. Settings
3. Project <project's name>
4. Python Interpreter

Then press the **plus** icon on your right (install), and type **pygame**. When you find the module, check the box *Specify version* and select the version you want.

If this version does not want, you can easily select and check the other versions.