# How to add/use libraries in Python (3.5.1)

Tags: python, lxml, libraries

I've recently been playing around with python and have now expanded into doing stuff like scraping through websites and other cool stuff and I need to import new libraries for these things like lxml, pandas, urllib2 and such. So I have Python 3.5.1 installed and is also using Wing IDE. I (think) also managed to install pip using this [tutorial](http://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing/), but then got lost after the

> Run python get-pip.py

part.

So how would I go about installing those libraries to try new projects? Thanks!

Comment: open up a command window and type `pip install lxml` ...

Comment: Python 3.5 comes with pip already installed.

Answer (score 0):

python 3.5 comes with pip already, to install something with it, open a cmd and do `python -m pip install library` to install your desire library and if you want the help on the command do `python -m pip --help`

Comment: thanks! this works. but I get some erorr when trying to install most libraries and the solution seems to be to install VS2015, the free one should be fine right. And then an error I get when trying to install BeautifulSoup about how there is a missing paranthesis, how can I fix that?

Comment: I don't know, I also have some problems installing numpy, but because I really don't need it yet I don't have search for a solution, sorry I can't help you more.

Comment: recently I install the anaconda distribution of python, it has included numpy that is the way I find to get it, it also has BeautifulSoup and many more cool stuff, you can try that :)

Answer (score 0):

if u have or you can create a file `requirements.txt` which contains the libraries that you want to install for ex:

```
numpy==1.14.2
Pillow==5.1.0
```

You gonna situate in your folder which contains that `requirements.txt` in my case the path to my project is

```
C:\Users\LE\Desktop\Projet2_Sig_Exo3\exo 3\k-means
```

now just type

```
python -m pip install -r ./requirements.txt
```

and all the libararies that you want gonna install

```
C:\Users\LE\Desktop\Projet2_Sig_Exo3\exo 3\k-means>python -m pip install -r ./requirements.txt
```