# Wrong folder after installing a wheel with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, setuptools, python-wheel

I have a python project that I want to distribute. I read multiple tutorials on how to write my setup.py file and how to install the produced wheel: [sample project example](https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject), [setup.py tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/distributing/#configuring-your-project), [wheel doc](https://wheel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), [wheel install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885397/how-do-i-install-a-python-package-with-a-whl-file) or [wheel install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21222114/how-do-i-install-python-libraries).

The structure of my project is:

```
project_name
    |_ lib
        |_ project_folder
        |_ py modules
    |_ test
    |_ setup.py
    |_README.rst
```

I build my wheel like this `python setup.py bdist_wheel` and then I take the produced wheel into another folder outside my project and do `pip install my_wheel`. I tried also `pip install --no-index --find-links=my_wheel project_name`

The problem is that when I look into my python `site-packages` folder, instead of having:

```
python folders
project_name
project_name-2.0.0.dist-info
```

the `project_name` folder is broken into lib and test:

```
python folders
lib
project_name-2.0.0.dist-info
test
```

I don't understand why my `project_name` isn't like the other python folders, grouped. Can someone help me understand better?

setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from codecs import open
from os import path

root_folder = path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))

with open(path.join(root_folder, "README.rst"), encoding="utf-8") as f:
    long_description = f.read()

setup(
    name = "project",
    version = "2.0.0",

    description = "My project is cool",
    long_description = long_description,     

    packages = find_packages(),

    include_package_data = True
)
```

Comment: Do your `lib` and `test` directories have `__init__.py` files, by any chance?

Comment: Yes they have. They musn't have it?

Comment: Nope, because they are not packages. `find_packages()` uses `__init__.py` files to detect what is a package.

Answer (score 3):

`find_packages()` determines packages by the `__init__.py` files. It looks like your `lib` and `tests` directories have `__init__.py` files in them.

Neither your `lib` or `tests` directories are packages, remove the `__init__.py` files from those. That way `find_packages()` will only include `project_folder()` in the resulting distribution (source, binary or wheel).

Comment: I tested that way (btw you were right `lib` and `tests` weren't supposed to be packages) but I still don't have my `project_folder` as a folder, only the `project_folder-2.0.0.dist-info`. I don't see why because I have the message `installing collected packages project_folder` so I thought that I would see my folder

Comment: @user3314570: was the wheel cache used? I'd first build a `sdist` tarball and inspect what is being put in that, *then* try to install it as a wheel (making sure to uninstall the old and that no cached wheel is used instead).

Comment: I'm new to this method so I don't know what is the wheel cache and how to deal with it. I've first done a sdist before wanting a wheel with `python setup.py sdist`. Inside Ihave my `project_folder` with it's lib and test folders inside as I wish.

Comment: Use `--no-cache-dir` to prevent the cache being used.

Comment: @user3314570: Ah, yes, the sdist would have that. Just checking: there a `__init__.py` in `project_folder`, right?

Comment: yes there is. This one has to be a package. So I write `pip install --no-cache-dir mywheel`?

Comment: Yes; you may want to include `--force-reinstall` or `--ignore-installed` too to avoid any issues with pip thinking it is already installed.

Comment: Still no sign of my `project_folder`, only the dist-info. I tested with a fake project, very simple which only contained one package folder and the setup and it worked fine. So I tested to take out my `project_folder`out of my lib folder to test if that way it will work, but still no..

Comment: At this point I can't help you any further; provide a [mcve] that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your help and time. I deleted the lib folder and placed directly my `project_folder`at the root and it worked.