# How do I add a new module in python?

Tags: python

I am rather new to python and am trying to run a written script that starts with

`import numpy as np`

When I run the script, it says it can't find the module `numpy`.

How do I find and install new modules such as `numpy`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Python libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21222114/how-do-i-install-python-libraries)

Answer (score 2):

The package manager for python (e.g equivalent to `apt` for Ubuntu) is called [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/). When you need to install a package, say numpy, you have to type `pip install numpy.`

Comment: If you are using Python 3 you should use pip3 instead of pip

Answer (score -1):

### Installing via pip

```
python -m pip install --user numpy scipy matplotlib ipython jupyter pandas sympy nose
```

### Install system-wide via a Linux package manager (Ubuntu)

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy python-matplotlib ipython ipython-notebook python-pandas python-sympy python-nose
```

## Install system-wide via a Mac package manager

Macports:

```
sudo port install py35-numpy py35-scipy py35-matplotlib py35-ipython +notebook py35-pandas py35-sympy py35-nose
```

Homebrew:

```
python -m pip install numpy scipy matplotlib
```

Reference: https://www.scipy.org/install.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20861950)

Comment: @phe oh yes sorry I forgot about that. Give me some time to edit the answer.