# Install local, downloaded WHL files in Pycharm Community 2019.3

Tags: python, pycharm, package, installation, local

I have a standalone Windows 10 machine - no connection to the outside world.  I have downloaded some whl  & tar.gz files to install into a new project virtual environment.  I don't care whether I do it through Pycharms Settings (easiest/prefered) or through the command line, but I cannot seem to make it happen.  This is going to be repeated, a lot, can someone please help me with a solid work-around?

Comment: I found my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21222114/how-do-i-install-python-libraries-in-wheel-format

Answer (score 0):

Just use pip. Activate your virtual environment and install it

```
pip install some_package.whl
```