# E: Unable to locate package pyPdf

Tags: python, package, pypdf

I'm trying to install pyPdf by uising this command( sudo apt-get install pyPdf)

But i'm getting the following.....
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pyPdf

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Python libraries in wheel format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21222114/how-do-i-install-python-libraries-in-wheel-format)

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the official instructions: https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/installation.html

```
pip install pypdf
```

Depending on your system it might be pip3 instead of pip

You might also need to add a --user flag of you don't have admin permissions on your system