# Run scrapy under windows 7

Tags: python, windows, pip, scrapy

I want to create a new scrappy project under `win 7`. I have installed scrapy over pip and everthing went find.

I am using `pip 1.0.1 from c:\python27\lib\site-packages (python 2.7)`.

I have added the `C:\Python27\Scripts` as my path variable.

However, when running scrapy in my cmd, I get:

```
C:\Users\User\EclipseWorkspace>scrapy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\scrapy-script.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 2709, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 686, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 584, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: six>=1.5.2
```

Any recommendation what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

**Update**

When installing pip again I get:

```
C:\Users\User\EclipseWorkspace>pip --version
pip 6.0.6 from C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-6.0.6-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)
```

However, when running scrapy:

```
C:\Users\User\EclipseWorkspace>scrapy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\scrapy-script.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 2709, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 686, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 584, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: six>=1.5.2
```

Comment: ref this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200056/pip-broke-how-to-fix-distributionnotfound-error

Comment: aren't you just missing six package ? Install it with pip install six or pip install --upgrade six