# Trouble getting pip to work DistributionNotFound

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, python-imaging-library

i recently with Python coding a little programm with a simple GUI (Tkinter).
Now i need PIL to use images.
I want to install PIL using PIP but.
After installing PIP it always gives me this output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2872, in <module>


  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 451, in _build_master
    def _build_from_requirements(cls, req_spec):
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 464, in _build_from_requirements
    for entry in sys.path:
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 639, in resolve
    fallback=True):
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pip==1.5.6
```

Does anyone know what happend here?
I'm using Elementary OS Freya (Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: Are you inside a virtualenv?

Comment: no I dont think so. I'm programming in PyCharm

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200056/pip-broke-how-to-fix-distributionnotfound-error seems helpful