# Centos 6.5 error installing wal-e

Tags: python, pip

On a fresh CentOS 6.5 install (Python 2.6.6), after doing `pip install wal-e` successfully, running wal-e gives the following error:

```
# wal-e
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/wal-e", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2655, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 648, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 546, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: argparse>=0.8
```

If i do `pip list argparse` I get a bunch of stuff, including argparse 1.3.0

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the argparse package.  wal-e is looking for version 0.8 or higher.

```
pip install argparse
```

Also see this:
[pip broke. how to fix DistributionNotFound error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200056/pip-broke-how-to-fix-distributionnotfound-error)

Comment: @MarkFletcher Edited original post.  I've also found that if you don't use the same installation procedure -- same tool, same user account -- that you can cause issues.  I also suggest a virtualenv if you have several different configurations.

Comment: I saw that post, and tried upgrading pip, but that didn't help. I installed pip using yum. I've also tried different versions of wal-e. And I've tried uninstalling/installing argparse.

Comment: Are you installing as the same user?  Also, try upgrading the pip tool itself; pip install --upgrade pip

Comment: Also, in that link, see the part about python-setup tools for CentOS.

Comment: Yep, did all that. When upgrading pip, I get an InsecurePlatformWarning. The version of pip is 7.0.3