# Cannot run django-admin

Tags: django, ubuntu

I am not able to run django admin on a Ubuntu server. Note that I have created one django project before.
I have python and django correctly installed:

```
user@server:~$ python -c "import django; print(django.get_version())"
1.8.4*
```

I am getting the following error:

```
user@server:~$ django-admin
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/django-admin", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2672, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 654, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 552, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: Django==1.8.4
```

What am I possibly doing wrong?

Comment: maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200056/pip-broke-how-to-fix-distributionnotfound-error useful for you

Comment: Thank you @okuznetsov. this perfecty solved my issue. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it with the help of @okuznetsov.
I need to upgrade django.

```
user@server:~$ sudo easy_install --upgrade django
```