# Python2 - Unable to run pyinstaller

Tags: python, pip, pyinstaller

I installed pyinstaller using pip

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

but when I run it I get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/pyinstaller", line 7, in <module>
  from PyInstaller.__main__ import run
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
  __version__ = pkg_resources.get_distribution('PyInstaller').version
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 330, in get_distribution
  if isinstance(dist,Requirement): dist = get_provider(dist)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 209, in get_provider
  return working_set.find(moduleOrReq) or require(str(moduleOrReq))[0]
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 686, in require
  needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 584, in resolve
  raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: PyInstaller
```

I cannot figure out what the issue is, I have tried reinstalling it. I have googled the error but no results come up that help.

Does anyone know a fix?

Comment: Is your pip updated? Try to run run pip install --upgrade pip

Comment: Just did it, I just reinstalled pyinstaller too, I still get the error.

Comment: check this link, maybe one of this answers can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200056/pip-broke-how-to-fix-distributionnotfound-error

Comment: Didn't work sadly