# pip install not working, Distribution not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, installation, anaconda

I am trying to install Pip and anaconda.

In my mac I have both python 2 as well as python 3.

When I try to `easy_install pip` I get the error `[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-14341.write-test'`

So I tried to do a `pip install`

**I GOT**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3241, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3225, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3254, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 585, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 598, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 786, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==19.3.1' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

**Also I cannot install Anaconda, maybe because of this problem**

PS. I have used homebrew to install python.

Have anyone solved it?

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200056/pip-broke-how-to-fix-distributionnotfound-error ?

Comment: a) easy_install is deprecated. Don't use it, b) Permission denied is self-describing - use `sudo`. Although I suppose you're doing smth. wrong from start

Comment: Recommendation - focus strictly on Python 3. Python 2 has reached End of Life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the problem is that from now on we to use `pip3` instead of just `pip`. Another problem is that the `open ~/.zshrc` file need to be updated with the same `open ~/.bash_profile` instruction from anaconda.

**IN CONCLUSION**

I think that for installing pip packages you need to use the `pip3` command or you could write an alias file where you substitute pip with pip3.

Then for actually using `conda` I followed this article so that it overrun the zhs of the mac config.

[Getting Anaconda to work](https://medium.com/@sumitmenon/how-to-get-anaconda-to-work-with-oh-my-zsh-on-mac-os-x-7c1c7247d896)